# Generate page citations with chapter numbers using DocBook/XLST-FO

Tags: xslt, apache-fop, docbook, docbook-xsl

I'm able to generate a page number given an ID passed: `<fo:page-number-citation ref-id="{$id}"/>`.

However, I'm unable to find a reliable way to fetch the chapter number.

Ideally, I would like to have all calls to `fo:page-number-citation` to be of the format **ChapterNum-PageNum**.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PrintHeaders.html#PageNumberPrefix

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that! I'll give it a shot tonight and report back.

Comment: @mzjn It looks like that was the ticket! I'll do a write up soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](https://github.com/docbook/wiki/wiki/PageNumberPrefixes) to the DocBook wiki helps.

For example, the following snippet displays the chapter number: `<xsl:number count="chapter" from="book" level="any"/>` when under the `chapter` element.

```
<fo:basic-link internal-destination="{$refname.id}">
  <xsl:number count="chapter" from="book" level="any"/>
  <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
  <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="{$refname.id}"/>
</fo:basic-link>
```